# Why notifyAll() function isn't working here? How can I edit it?

Tags: android

Why isn't notifyAll() function working here? What should I edit in order to make it work?

```
protected synchronized String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    switch (method) {
        case "GET":
            data = req.getRequest(urls[0]);
            break;
        case "POST":
            data = req.postRequest(urls[0]);
            break;
    }

    notifyAll();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: where does that method comes (switch (method))? Is that a global variable?

Comment: What's not working? Please, provide more info

Comment: when send a request it return null

Comment: post your code with `wait()` statement, and specify what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You're locking on the inner class object by putting the synchronized in the method, replace it to [synchronized block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) and create field (class scope) object as a locker.